# SetInterval in Opera causes select blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opera, setinterval

I need to group tooltips about errors showed by jQuery Validator. So I have written simple loop with setInterval to check if in the same row are more than one input with error class.

```
   setInterval(function() {
      $('.xrror').remove();
      $('div.row-4:has([name].error)').each(function() {
         var tmp = $('[name].error', this);
         if(tmp.length > 1) {
            $('label.error', this).hide();

            tmp.last().parent().append(
               $(document.createElement('label')).addClass('error').addClass('xrror').append(
                  $(document.createElement('span')).text('Fields with errors were marked with red color')
               )
            );
         } else {
            $('[name].error', this).parent().find('label.error').show();
         }
      });
   }, 50);
```

And in Opera it's causing blinking on opened Select element.

Comment: The "blink" you see are from the `.xrror` elements being removed and added in a very short time. Some browsers skip rendering this altogether, but it is not the case for Opera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a setInterval function every 50 miliseconds, which will consume a lot of resources, you should bind your function on events like submit, or change. As it seems to be related to a form validation, you do not need to do anything unless the user modify a field.